# Problem with RequireJS in SuiteScript 2.0 server-side environment

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

We are trying to get [core-js@3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js) to work properly in the SuiteScript 2.0 server-side execution environment, for all of its (very nice to have) ECMAScript 6 polyfills.

The bundled version of the library seems to work fine. For example, this works OK in the Script Debugger:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 */
require(['/SuiteScripts/core'],
  function() {
    var test = Array.from(new Set([1, 2, 3, 2, 1]));
  }
);
```

(Where /SuiteScripts/core.js is the [version 3.6.4 bundled version of the library](https://unpkg.com/core-js-bundle@3.6.4/index.js).)

However, we'd prefer to use the standard (unbundled) version of the library because this will allow us to selectively load only the features we need. We uploaded version 3.6.4 of the library to our File Cabinet and then tried to load it:

[image: File Cabinet]

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 */
require(['/SuiteScripts/core-js'],
  function() {
    var test = Array.from(new Set([1, 2, 3, 2, 1]));
  }
);
```

This results in the following error:

```
{"type":"error.SuiteScriptModuleLoaderError","name":"MODULE_DOES_NOT_EXIST","message":"Module does not exist: /SuiteScripts/core-js.js","stack":["<anonymous>(adhoc$-1$debugger.user:4)"]}
```

It appears that RequireJS is doing something weird in the SuiteScript 2.0 environment, because normally, referring to a directory from `require()` should cause RequireJS to look for an `index.js` in the directory? If we refer to the `index.js` file in the directory directly, then we just get a different error when the `index.js` file tries to `require('./es')` the `es` subdirectory:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 */
require(['/SuiteScripts/core-js/index'],
  function() {
    var test = Array.from(new Set([1, 2, 3, 2, 1]));
  }
);
```

Error message:

```
{"type":"error.SuiteScriptModuleLoaderError","name":"{stack=[Ljava.lang.Object;@73882a5d, toJSON=org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction@53fe9f7f, name=MODULE_DOES_NOT_EXIST, toString=org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction@32f5a028, id=, message=Module does not exist: /es.js, TYPE=error.SuiteScriptModuleLoaderError}","message":"","stack":["<anonymous>(adhoc$-1$debugger.user:4)"]}
```

We have tried various mechanisms of modifying the RequireJS configuration that we found suggested in NetSuite documentation and on the web, such as `@NAmdConfig /Directory/...` JSDoc argument, and `require.config(...)`, with no success. `@NAmdConfig` seems to be totally ignored in every execution context we have tried it in, and `require.config(...)` can't be used to mutate the primary RequireJS context configuration.

**Is `index.js` resolution simply broken in SuiteScript 2.0's RequireJS implementation? Are there any work arounds?**

Comment: Can you share the directory structure from where your source NetSuite entry level script resides? that would help to zero-in on your problem. From what I could gather was you had your source NS script in some other directory, so could try using `define(['require'], function (require) { })` in your source script file? You can check [this](https://medium.com/@avivashisth/netsuite-optimizing-suitescript-with-progressive-loading-35332dcc6502) out for further clarification.

Comment: The simplified entry point script I referenced in my OP was copy-pasted directly into the Script Debugger to make it easier for other people to reproduce... however, we have observed the same behavior in scripts which we run from the File Cabinet. I read the article that you linked to, but I don't think it addresses the problem we are trying to solve. Loading require with ```define(['require'], function (require) { })``` did not fix the ```index.js``` resolution problem that I described.

Comment: i think you could use `paths` attribute 
```js
   require({ paths  : {

Answer (score 4):

NetSuite uses a customized version of `require`, with no documentation on exactly what said customizations are. For best results, you will want to use minified, rolled-up versions of any libraries you want.

If you want to pick and choose features of `core-js`, you should use `webpack` or `rollup` or whatever compilation tool you want to build the library the way you want, then import the single resulting file in your SuiteScript modules.

Alternatively, if your goal is ES6+ features, you can try using SuiteScript 2.1 instead.

Comment: We are using minified, bundled libraries now. This does "work". However, it doesn't solve the problem I stated in my OP which is that we'd like to find a way to import specific features from unbundled libraries rather than loading (for example) an entire bundled core-js, which is over 500 KiB, every time one of our scripts runs. SS2.1 isn't a solution for us either because the Script Debugger and Client Scripts don't work with it.

Comment: Is the size of importing the whole library causing you a problem? In my experience, saving a few milliseconds on module load is never noticeable in NetSuite due to the fact that executing anything of import (searches, record loading, HTTP requests) operates on the order of seconds.

Comment: Further, Client Scripts leverage the Browser's JS engine, so as long as your users are using a reasonably modern browser, you should have access to all modern JS features.

Comment: Loading large modules in the server-side execution context might be fast today, because NetSuite uses an interpreted run-time environment, but if they were ever to switch to a compiled run-time environment this could bite us in a big way. Furthermore, NetSuite inexplicably seems to send HTTP Pragma: No-Cache with each client script and all custom modules? Meaning, you are redownloading all client scripts and custom modules every time you load a page in NetSuite. Our attitude is the opposite of yours – performance in NetSuite is already bad enough, let's not make it worse on our account.

Answer (score 0):

as per [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4599733337.html) i think you could use the `paths` property in a `requirecfg.json` lik this:

```json
  {
    "paths": {
      "core": "SuiteScripts/core-js"
    }
  }
```

Then call it from your modules using your path for `core`:

```js
/**
 *
 * @NAmdConfig /SuiteScripts/requirecfg.json
 */
define([ 'core/index.js' ], (cIndex) => {
  //
});
```